# Detect a string in Google Sheet and output a different string based on the result

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I use REGEXMATCH to detect strings in a sheet. I need to replace the cells values by texts.

For example, detect "One" and output "Text one", detect "Two" and output "A second text", detect "three" and output "Another text".*

I already use :

```
=IF(OR(REGEXMATCH('Sheet'!A2;"One");REGEXMATCH('Sheet'!A2;"Two"));"Texte 1";"My second text")
```

But it's only based on TRUE/FALSE, I will have up to 4 possibilities.

Comment: Your formula is not just replacing the part "One" of a string, but returning a totally different string. Is this the intention? The text is written as 'detect "One" and replace it by'....  what is "it" here, the word "One" or the entire string? Sample input and desired output would help to clarify.

Comment: Sorry @if.... I misspoke : In my Sheet 1, cell A2, "One" ->  Sheet 2, cell B2, "Texte number one".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[IFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145) allows more conditions:

```
=IFS(REGEXMATCH(A1,"One"),1,REGEXMATCH(A1,"Two"),2, ...)
```

Comment: I can't make it work... I cant find the "IFS" Syntax in french. On Google Support page there is no translation.

Comment: Ok, so there is no translation for IFS, its a bit strange because Syntax element like IF (SI) is translated yet. Its working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with substitute. You may need to replace my ',' with ';' for the language difference.

```
=substitute(substitute(substitute(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"One","Teste 1"),"Two","My second text"),"Three","My third text"),"Four", "My fourth text")
```